# Microsoft Dynamics API - Incident returned fields

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm trying to make a get call to our Dynamics CRM via the API for the entity "Incident". It returns a lot of fields if I request a specific incident record but a particular custom boolean field which is present on all incident records is not. This is a pain as this is the specific field I need to filter on to get the records I want. I can see other custom fields are returned in the api call but I just can't figure out how it's decided which fields are exposed and which aren't. Any help would be much appreciated.

For context, I'm writing a small application which will pull all records for the current date where this particular boolean = true and then format details from each return record into an email template.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen For example, if I do something so simple as:

`https://our_dynamics_uri.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/incidents?$filter=apitil_uniqueid eq 'ZZZ-12345'`

I would get a response with a JSON containing fields assocaited with incidents and the values relevant for that incident ticket. I don't however get the field I'm interested in.

Comment: When you do receive the record along with its attribute values, the reason why you do not get the field you're looking for, does not have a value. Try this filter: `$filter=apitil_uniqueid ne null`

Comment: That's not really my problem, I know the boolean field in question exists and is set to yes for an example incident. I suspect the issue is that the field I want to query on exists on a separate solution to the Default Solution. The fields returned only seems to be ones from the default solution except one, which is from the same solution that my boolean field exists in. So there must be a way to define which fields are returned.

Comment: @EdMan888 can you show us what happens when you add $select clause in query and add the field in question to that $select list ? Also edit the question and add details pls

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

To include the field in question in resultset, try adding `$select=title,apitil_customfield` in web api query.

```
https://our_dynamics_uri.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/incidents?$select=title,apitil_customfield,createdon,createdby&$filter=apitil_uniqueid eq 'ZZZ-12345'
```